# How to use Async task in android tablayout activity...?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, asynchronous

Hello everyone in need to know what is the proper way of using the Async in tab Layout Activity.

In my task there a activity with two tabs.

**Tab1** and **Tab2**

Tab1  Load data from server and show the data.

Tab2  Also load the another data from server and show the data in list view.

im using Async Task in tab1 and tab2   but the problem is when the activity started  then the both **Async Task class execute** at same time that cause the error .

i need how to use it' sapratly when first tab fragment is visable then run the rirst **Async Task** and when second fragment is visable then run the **2nd Async Task**  one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both scenario :

1) You can call both `AsyncTasks` in your activity and show data in your both tabs.

2) As per issue

> im using Async Task in tab1 and tab2 but the problem is when the activity started then the both Async Task class execute at same time that cause the error .

You should execute your `AsyncTask` in `setUserVisibleHint()`method which will call when your fragments completely visible.

**Use:**

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
      // execute your asynctask here
    }
}
```

Comment: where  and how to use setUserVisibleHint() method

Comment: Its a override method of fragment. So you need to call both in _Tab1_ and _Tab2_

Comment: thnx bro i will try

Comment: @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        new DownloadFilesTask(getContext()).execute();
    }


Cause NullPointerException

Comment: Your _getContext()_ is null. You should use _getActivity()_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118914/discussion-between-sunny-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you'd better using only one Async Task to get data from server then handle with tabs one by one

Comment: You could use a bus, for example with the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android
and you can either  use a bus or static variable

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnTabSelectedListener` to your `TabLayout`

```
// run asynctask 1 first and then
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0)
                // run asynctask 1
            else // run asynctask2
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```